# Symfony process component points to wrong PHP version

Tags: php, symfony, process

I am trying to run `composer install` with the Symfony process component like this:

```
if ($process->isSuccessful()) {
    $process = new Process("cd {$directory} && composer install");

    $process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
        if (Process::ERR === $type) {
            Log::info($buffer);
        } else {
            Log::info($buffer);
        }
    });
}
```

It points to a PHP version of 5.6.25 which looks really strange because I am 100% certain I am using PHP 7. Running a phpinfo() inside Laravel gives me:

> PHP Version 7.0.13

Running `php -v` from my terminal gives me:

> PHP 7.0.13 (cli) (built: Nov 15 2016 23:52:36) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2016 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016
>   Zend Technologies

This is the output that I am tailing from my log file which the Symfony process component is writing to:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 5.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[5.0.0].
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 5.0.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 6.0.6 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.0.6].
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.6 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 4.0.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects[4.0.0].
    - phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects 4.0.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.25) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Does anybody know why it points to a PHP version I am not using? I am running this on macOS by the way.

The strangest thing is that even if I use `php -v` in the Symfony process it shows that right version so it seems composer links to a wrong PHP version? I was able to install it locally though with composer by simply requiring it through my own terminal.

If anybody needs more information I am more than willing to try some things. Let me know.

Comment: Are there more than one version of php installed in your machine? try `which php` to confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because the user that executes the symfony process component is different than my normal user which results in a totally different `$PATH` which does not have the usual globals that I had set.

If you would like to read up on this you could check out this discussion:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21591

Answer (score 1):

Don't know for sure why this is happening, but you can skip platform requisites in composer with [`--ignore-platform-reqs` option](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install).

```
if ($process->isSuccessful()) {
    $process = new Process("cd {$directory} && composer install --ignore-platform-reqs");

    $process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
        if (Process::ERR === $type) {
            Log::info($buffer);
        } else {
            Log::info($buffer);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly but I am still really wary for the underlying issue. Thanks for replying but I would love for somebody to still solve this with me if possible :)